# Java spring @RequestParam JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, request

current controller code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/city", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String getWeather(@RequestParam("city") int city_id,
                             @RequestParam("text") String days, //this gives errrors, when i remove this line, then it is okay
                             Model model) {
    logger.debug("Received request to show cities page");
    //int city = 

    // Attach list of subscriptions to the Model
    model.addAttribute("city",  service.getCity(city_id));

    // This will resolve to /WEB-INF/jsp/subscribers.jsp
    return "city";
}
```

this is my JSP file(view):

```
    <form method="post" action="/spring/krams/show/city">
Vali linn
<select name="city">
    <c:forEach items="${cities}" var="city">
        <option value="<c:out value="${city.id}" />"><c:out value="${city.city}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
</select><br>
Vali prognoos N päeva kohta(kirjuta 1 hetkese ilma jaoks)
<input type="text name="text">
<input type="submit" value="Test" name="submit" />
</form>
```

i want to get a value from the textbox named TEXT, but when i press the submit button then i get

```
HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().
```

Comment: there seems to be a problem here .. `<input type="text name="text">
` .. change to `<input type="text" name="text">` and try. I think `syntactically incorrect` means the names specified in the @RequestParam annotations don't match. possibly because of the above error in html.

Comment: @naiquevin: yeah that was the problem. if you would for an answer, then i could accept it...thanks...damn typos.i have deadline in 10 hours ..

Comment: i posted a comment as I wasn't much sure about it. Answered off the top of my head. glad that it helped.

Comment: @naiquevin add it as answer ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am adding this answer so that you can accept it, as it was suggested by Bozho :)

There seems to be a problem in the HTML: 
`<input type="text name="text">`

Change it to 
`<input type="text" name="text">` and try .

I think syntactically incorrect means the names specified in the `@RequestParam` annotations don't match with the request param names... possibly because of the above error in HTML.