# request sent by client is syntactically incorrect in windows

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc

I am having problem with my application as I  am using Apache Tomcat Server 7.0.26, Spring MVC 3.0, MySql, so my problem is

I have implemented Search page so, it sends the request parameter to controller and it works fine on Ubuntu but When I try it on Windows 7 it gives me error of: request sent by client is syntactically incorrect in windows.

Here's the code of my controller:

---

```
@RequestMapping(value="/viewSelectedAdvance") 
public ModelAndView showSelectedAdvance(@RequestParam(value="date",required=false) Date date,@RequestParam(value="date1",required=false) Date date1) { 
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("showSelectedAdvance"); 
    List<Expense> expense=reportDAO.getExpenseReport(date,date1);
    mav.addObject("EXPENSE_SELECTED_REPORT", expense); 
    System.out.println(date); 
    System.out.println(date1); 
    return mav; 
}
```

---

And my template:

---

```
<form action="viewSelectedAdvance.html" method="post">
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" y cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Start Date</td> 
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="date" id="dt" readonly="true"/>
                <a href="javascript:NewCal('dt','yyyymmdd')"></a>
            <td>Enter End Date</td>
            <input type="text" name="date1" id="dt1" readonly="true" />
            <a href="javascript:NewCal('dt1','yyyymmdd')"></a> 
            <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" onClick="javascript:getDate();" /> 
    </table>
</form>
```

How can I solve this problem

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 0):

see here:

[Java spring @RequestParam JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831239/java-spring-requestparam-jsp)

As you didn't provide any code, I'm just guessing that this is your problem.

---

Update:

Replace your template with this (cleaned up version):

```
<form action="viewSelectedAdvance.html" method="post">
    <table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" y cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> 
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Start Date</td> 
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="date" id="dt" readonly="true"/>
                <a href="javascript:NewCal('dt','yyyymmdd')"></a>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Enter End Date</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="date1" id="dt1" readonly="true" />
                <a href="javascript:NewCal('dt1','yyyymmdd')"></a> 
                <input type="submit" value="Generate Report" onClick="javascript:getDate();" /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

And what are the "invisible" links for?

Comment: thanks, but Everything is fine with my code as, it works fine with ubuntu 11.0 but I am getting problem on windows 7

Comment: if you could post your code (controller and template), i (or someone else) might actually be able to help you.

Comment: Heres my code of controller:- @RequestMapping(value="/viewSelectedAdvance")
 public ModelAndView showSelectedAdvance(@RequestParam(value="date",required=false) Date date,@RequestParam(value="date1",required=false) Date date1) 
 {
  ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView("showSelectedAdvance");
  
  List<Expense> expense=reportDAO.getExpenseReport(date,date1);
  mav.addObject("EXPENSE_SELECTED_REPORT", expense);
  System.out.println(date);
  System.out.println(date1);
  return mav;
 }

Comment: ok, thanks. could you please post the template too? don't hold back, better too much code than not enough.

Comment: Heres mjsp code: <form action="viewSelectedAdvance.html" method="post">
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" y cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Enter Start Date</td> 
            <td>
             <input type="text" name="date" id="dt" readonly="true"/><a href="javascript:NewCal('dt','yyyymmdd')"></a>
<td>Enter End Date</td> 
<input type="text" name="date1" id="dt1"  readonly="true" /><a href="javascript:NewCal('dt1','yyyymmdd')"></a>
<input type="submit" value="Generate Report" onClick="javascript:getDate();" />  
    </table>
    </form>

Comment: I added both your code snippets to the question. While formatting it, I noticed you have errors in your template (HTML tags not closed and so on). I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks, The problem is solve I just changed the request parameter to String From Date and typecased to Date in controller field. But,I am amused that the String parameter works why Date parameter doesn't work for Windows 7

Comment: ok, thanks for sharing. String message though. I guess it could come from differences in date formatting.